# Nasm: Convert integer to string using preprocessor

Tags: assembly, preprocessor, nasm

How does one convert an integer to a string using the Nasm preprocessor? For example, consider the following code:

```
%define myInt 65
%define myString 'Sixty-five is ', myInt
```

The symbol `myString` will evaluate to `Sixty-five is A`. The desired result is `Sixty-five is 65`. How can I achieve this? It seems like such a trivial question, but the Nasm documentation has yielded nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code

```
%define myInt 65
%define quot "
%define stringify(x) quot %+ x %+ quot
%strcat myString 'Sixty-five is ', stringify(myInt)

bits 32
db myString
```

produces the following listing file:

```
 1                                  %define myInt 65
 2                                  %define quot "
 3                                  %define stringify(x) quot %+ x %+ quot
 4                                  %strcat myString 'Sixty-five is ', stringify(myInt)
 5                                  
 6                                  bits 32
 7 00000000 53697874792D666976-     db myString
 8 00000009 65206973203635
```

and the following binary:

```
0000000000: 53 69 78 74 79 2D 66 69 │ 76 65 20 69 73 20 36 35  Sixty-five is 65
```

I used NASM version 2.10 compiled on Mar 12 2012.

Comment: Not sure this works with newer versions of NASM, as you can probably use something like `%defstr`

Comment: Off topic, but figured I'd ping you from here. In your Smaller-C - is there a way to force it to generate 8086 code only? I noticed some generated code had `movzx`. I may have missed the option in the docs although I only saw `-seg16`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch `#include <sys/80186.h>` is the closest you can get right now.

Answer (score 2):

You should use %defstr macro.

```
%define myInt 65
%defstr strInt myInt
%define myString 'Sixty-five is ', strInt
```

https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.1.9

Answer (score 0):

At the moment can't test this with NASM, but this works at least in YASM (I added a Linux x86-64 printing code to make testing easier):

```
[bits 64]

%define myInt 65
%define myTens myInt/10 + 48
%define myOnes myInt-(myInt/10)*10 + 48
%define myString 'Sixty-five is ', myTens, myOnes

section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov edi,1   ; STDOUT        
    mov rsi,my_string
    mov edx,my_string_length    ; length of string in bytes.
    mov eax,1   ; write
    syscall

    xor edi,edi
    mov eax,60  ; exit
    syscall

section .data
my_string db myString
db 0x0a
my_string_length equ $-my_string
```