# Incorporate constant into byte array as ASCII correct code

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, stringification

I have some numeric constants in my data definition and would like to be able to use them inside my strings without having to embed them at runtime. Is this possible in MASM?

```
.data

LOWER_BOUND = 50
UPPER_BOUND = 100

promptMessage  BYTE  "Please enter a number between ", LOWER_BOUND, " and ", UPPER_BOUND, ".",10,13,0
```

I am using the Irvine library.

Comment: NASM can stringify constants at assemble time with its preprocessor: [Nasm: Convert integer to string using preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15650276).  (Which you can then use in the list of operands to `db`).  I don't know if MASM can do the same, or if so how.  You could do something like `BYTE (LOWER_BOUND/10)%10 + '0', LOWER_BOUND%10 + '0'` to do it explicitly for a 2-digit number, or any other fixed width with leading zeros, but variable-width needs something conditional.